# An adjective for a secret that is known to a third party

Tags: adverbs

I am writing some text for a piece of software and am stuck with this sentence:

> Use this function if you think that your private key has become known to a third party.

While the sentence explains very well when you should use a specific function, I take issue with the last part `has become known to a third party`. I feel that it's too long and not good enough to emphasize what I mean.

I have been looking at `compromised`, but that means that the situation happened because of `indiscreet, foolish, or reckless behavior` (Oxford American Dictionary), which might not be the case.

I also gave `leaked` a try, but that has the connotation that something was knowingly published to a broader audience, which is not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is an adverb that explains exactly the situation, where a private key to access certain information was obtained by a third party, which can then use it for malicious purposes (they use it for themselves).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The use of compromised referring to encryption keys which can no longer be trusted is something that has been used pretty commonly. If a third party has obtained a secret key something indiscreet has almost been guaranteed to have happened. Changing the phrase to "private key has been compromised" is short and to the point.

Given the context, I think **compromised** is an excellent choice.

Comment: +1 I agree that *compromised* is likely the best choice. Other options might be *revealed* or *exposed*.

Comment: OP has already considered and nearly rejected the option. He has also explained why.

Comment: This fits exactly the question's last paragraph (assuming that *adverb* should be *verb*).

Comment: I am inclined to accept this answer because of the reasoning that someone had to be indiscreet (even if it is not the user's fault). But I'll give the question a minimum 24h run before deciding.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, I had missed your "exposed" comment when I put that in an answer (oversight, not theft).  Should I remove my answer?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Certainly not.

Answer (score 3):

Per [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54223/8816), *compromised* is the best choice.  If that is not acceptable, you could also say that the private key has been *exposed*.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your reasons for rejecting *compromised*, but I think it is the most common expression for this instance.

Since *compromise* won't suit, you might consider **[expropriated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expropriated)**, which means "to take (something) from another's possession for one's own use."